# How to add quotation marks in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, quotation-marks

Hi I have an array using a code below

```
var selectedValues=new Array();
selectedValues=divisi.split(",");
```

and the result is

> ITD, ITO, Keuangan, Sumber Daya Manusia

But I want to have a result like

> "ITD", "ITO", "Keuangan", "Sumber Daya Manusia"

Do you know how to make it like that? thankyou

Comment: its in javascript or php?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not PHP. Javascript maybe?

Comment: yeah I'm sorry, it's javascript

Answer (score 0):

The split would return an array of strings itself, if that is the question.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Edit:
Adding a more detailed answer:

```
<?php

$divisi = "ITD, ITO, Keuangan, Sumber Daya Manusia";
$selectedValues = array();
$selectedValues = split(",", $divisi);
var_dump($selectedValues)

?>
```

The script above returns the below array when run on http://phpfiddle.org/

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "ITD" [1]=> string(4) " ITO" [2]=> string(9) " Keuangan" [3]=> string(20) " Sumber Daya Manusia" }
```

As pointed out `split` is deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php. Please use `explode` or `str_split`

Also your code looks like it is JavaScript and not proper PHP. So take care of that.

Comment: This can be a comment

Comment: Did you notice that he is not using PHP?

Comment: Did you notice it is tagged php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/qLa6wuch/)

```
var divisi = ['ITD', 'ITO', 'Keuangan', 'Sumber Daya Manusia']; //you can use user defined array or direct variable divisi
console.log('"'+divisi.join('\",\"')+'"'); //"ITD","ITO","Keuangan","Sumber Daya Manusia"
```

Comment: I am adding `var arr = [divisi];

     a=console.log('"'+arr.join('\",\"')+'"');
      alert(a);` but it's undefine and just show "ITD, ITO, Keuangan, Sumber Daya Manusia" in console

Comment: you need to use `var arr = divisi;`

Comment: I've got an error "Uncaught TypeError: arr.join is not a function" if I use `var arr = divisi;`

Comment: if `divisi` is a string then you need convert it into array `selectedValues=divisi.split(",");`.

Comment: are these correct? (My `ITD, ITO, Keuangan, Sumber Daya Manusia` is defined as  `divisi`)

`var selectedValues=new Array();
      selectedValues=divisi.split(",");
     
      var arr = divisi;

     a=console.log('"'+arr.join('\",\"')+'"');
      alert(a);`

Comment: you can not store console.log in a variable, you can check with inspect of the browser and console tab.

Comment: or, `var selectedValues=new Array(); selectedValues=divisi.split(","); var arr = divisi; alert('"'+arr.join('\",\"')+'"');`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: arr.join is not a function